# C - grandchild process

Tags: c, process, fork, posix

Is there a way to make that one parent process make two children an then these two children make their own children?
I thought that i will make a loop inside two children with fork in it is that a correct way?

Comment: There isn't any standard way, but there's nothing stopping you from doing what you describe. Just think it through, maybe diagram on paper what you plan to write, then implement it.

Comment: so i tried what i wrote and its working like i expected

Answer (score 1):

Since a child process is itself a process in its own right, it can as well have children.

Comment: thx i thought that process could be created only from parent and not from forked child